# Laravel 4 always returns HTTP status code 200

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have below code in error.php, which is triggered using `App::abort(404, $error)` in my controller. Still my response status code is 200(ok). I tried with various error codes like 400, 403

```
// NotFoundException handler
App::error(function(NotFoundException $e)
{
    $default_message = 'The requested resource was not found';

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => $e->getMessage() ?: $default_message,
    ), 404);
 });
```

Comment: Do you get the json message indicating that this error has actually triggered?

Comment: yes I am getting the actual error message in JSON format. I am interrupting the status code from the response and displaying messages in View

Comment: This looks more like a bug report that should be filed on [GitHub](http://github.com/laravel/framework/issues).  You've certainly not asked any question!

Comment: Initially it was working from the controllers and from error.php. After some point it stopped working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone still googling this problem:

I was struggling with this problem for hours. For me the problem was caused by an issue with one of my controllers.

Check all of your controllers and make sure there are no spaces in front of the `<?php` tag. The <`?php` tag should be the very first thing in the file. A single space in front of the `<?php` tag in any of your controllers that are routed as such:

```
Route::controller('example', 'ExampleController');
```

Will cause all status codes to be 200.

Comment: I've checked all my controllers... still getting this problem.

Answer (score 7):

I believe, regardless, you should receive a 404 response, so there might be something else happening that's the result of code not included in your question.

That being said, the Exception class that is thrown for 404 is `NotFoundHttpException` rather than `NotFoundException`.

Since Laravel 4 uses Symfony's HttpKernal, that Exception is [here](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/Exception/NotFoundHttpException.php).

You can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L667) where `App::abort()` throws `NotFoundHttpException` when a 404 is triggered.

Therefore, your code should look like:

```
// NotFoundHttpException handler
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e)
{
    $default_message = 'The requested resource was not found';

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => $e->getMessage() ?: $default_message,
    ), 404);
 });
```

**Important**: This will only fire for a 404 status, as that's the corresponding code to NotFoundHttpException. Other status codes return other Exception classes. To capture **all** HTTP status error codes exceptions, type hint for [HttpException](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/Exception/HttpException.php) like so:

```
// HttpException handler
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $e)
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => $e->getMessage(),
    ), $e-> getStatusCode());
 });
```

Lastly, consider [using a bit of Content Negotiation when deciding to return JSON or HTML](http://fideloper.com/error-handling-with-content-negotiation).

Comment: I had to use the entire name `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` else it was giving a fatal error "Class HttpException does not exist"

Comment: Oh, totally - Sorry I should have pointed that out. I'll edit the answer to put that in

Comment: Just as a side note, App::error() passes the exception object and status code `App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)` so you can use `$code` rather than `$exception->getStatusCode()` if needs be

Answer (score 2):

The solution didn't worked for me, so in case anyone is still looking for an answer, I thought it be best to put it here instead of creating another question.

After some time I had this problem too, in my `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` I had:

```
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()
                ->json(['error' => ['No results']])
                ->header('status', 422);
        }
    }
```

This worked in my local environment, however, in the homolog environment (which reproduces the production environment, just to be clear) it didn't returned the correct status code.

After another look I started looking at Laravel's docs, and I changed the call to the following:

```
    return response()
        ->json(['error' => ['No results.']], 422);
```

And that did the trick. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found some space in front of <?php

Comment: I think you are actually trying to answer. Please elaborate and explain how your observation can help the asker with their problem. You can [edit] your post to add information.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove `dump` & other print functions

I was actively debugging when I noticed this issue. It was caused because I had `dump(...)` calls in the code at that time.

When I removed all my debug `dump` calls, the status code was correctly `404` again (using `abort(404`).

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent two days trying to fix a similar issue: no matter what header or status code i was trying to send with server response, i would always get a status code 200 with a default content-type of text/html. Laravel sanctum's csrf-cookie wouldn't work.

My problem was caused by a new line character at the top of a laravel config file.

Sample code:

```
` 
  //<--- \n
<?php

return [
    ...
];
```

`

To find the culprit file, in vscode, i used a regex search on all files of my project: \n+(<?php)

The original answer by knews12 was very useful to fix my problem, thanks.