# laravel 4 header status always return 200 (OK)

Tags: laravel-4, http-headers

I have a code below:

```
return Response::json($message,401);
```

It always return 200 OK status in my server.

The strange thing is it returned correct status code in my localhost (PHP 5.5), but when I deploy to web server (PHP 5.4.30), it always return 200 status code.

When I trace back the code, I found a difference in this file:

**\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response.php**

```
public function sendHeaders() {
  // headers have already been sent by the developer
    if (headers_sent()) {
        return $this;
    }
   ......
}
```

headers_sent() -> return false on my localhost, but return true on web server.

**Update:**

Not only Json resonse having problem, when I try to change the code as below:

```
http_response_code(401);
echo $message;
```

It will still always return with 200 code. 
But if I run the script outside of laravel as below:

```
<?php
http_response_code(401);
echo $message;
?>
```

It's working fine.

Is this problem because of the difference in PHP version ? 
If so, is there any way to workaround it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just because this is the top search on google for a similar search people should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724772/laravel-4-always-returns-http-status-code-200 as it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server meets the Laravel requirements:

1. PHP >= 5.4, which seems to be the case.
2. Install the PHP JSON extension if not already installed (`apt-get install php5-json`).
3. Install the MCrypt PHP Extension if not already installed (`apt-get install php5-mcrypt`).
4. Make sure the `app/storage` directory is writable by the web server.

Also make sure you have no trailing PHP closing tags (`?>`) in your PHP files, as they are known to cause the `headers already sent` problem.

Comment: yes, all the listed items meet Laravel requirements

Comment: I have the same problem here, reported as an Issue on Laravel Github, but they say its not a Laravel issue..